# IIS - Windows Authentication Module slowing whole website during AuthenticationRequest state

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

We have a monolith web app hosted on an on-prem windows server 2012 in IIS. The application is built using aspnet c# and leveraging windows authentication for auth(X/Z). The application becomes extremely slow over time and while inspecting the slowness we noticed in the View Requests tab of the application pool is that the requests are jammed up in AuthenticationRequest state of WindowsAuthentication module.

[image]

We are certain that resetting the app pool would resolve this issue but curious as to what is causing this behaviour? Is this some sort of memory leak in the application or IIS windows authentication is causing this.

We deployed the same app in the other app pool on the same machine and that doesn't produce the same behaviour.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it is sql server and windows auth mode is enabled in it

Comment: How many domain controllers do you have? Are you sure both web sites are using the same domain controller?

Comment: I don't know how many domain controllers are there.. but I am sure another website is set up exactly the same way as the first one. And since the second website is acting as a test website, it's not receiving that much load as the main website.